# Passing a function to a function in C++

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference

I have a root finding function with the signature:

`double root_find(double f(double), ...)` (the ellipsis just meaning that there are some other arguments that aren't relevant to this question.)

I can also declare the function with the signature:

```
double root_find(double(& f)(double), ...)
```

Either way, it works.  With the second signature it's pretty clear that I'm passing the function f by reference.  With the first signature, I have no idea what's going on.  Can someone explain?

Comment: Perhaps reading `std::function` documentation would be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like arrays, function types are adjusted to pointer-to-function type in a parameter declaration. Thus, `double root_find(double f(double))` means `double root_find(double (*f)(double))` - a function taking a pointer-to-function.

A reference-to-function and pointer-to-function are essentially the same, but the semantics for references and pointers still apply (references cannot be reassigned while pointers can, etc.). Also, they can both be called as a normal function as the syntax is unambiguously a function call in that case.

Comment: This is correct. For example, `pthreads` do this when entering a function.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, your compiler will decay it to be `double (*f)(double)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in first case it'll be `double (*)(double)`, in second - `double (&)(double)`